# How to declare variable and assign value into that in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I'm very new in postgresql. I read many posts in this questions, but still don't get correct answer in my simple problem and keep receiving syntax error. I'm trying declare new string variable named parents_d and in the following lines trying to assign new value as well. Please help me!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION retrieve_parents(cid integer) RETURNS text AS $$ 
BEGIN
    DECLARE pd text;    
    pd:= 'function';
    RETURN concat(cid,pd);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

ERROR:  duplicate declaration at or near "pd"
LINE 4:  pd:= 'function';
         ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: duplicate declaration at or near "pd"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 104

Comment: what error you get?   Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Do you know how to declare the variable and assign value in postgresql?

Comment: I simplified my problem. Please help me!

Comment: Actually I tried many times in different options. Always receiving some errors. There is now duplicate error. I'm sorry. I know it is very stupid basic question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try like this

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9f90d/1)**

```
CREATE FUNCTION retrieve_parents(cid integer) RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE pd text;    
BEGIN

    pd:= 'function';
    RETURN concat(cid,pd);

END; $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working great! Can I ask you one more question? Is pd a local variable or global? If the function is recursive, is it fine?

Comment: Yes, is local. If the function is recursive should be ok. You can always use `RAISE NOTICE 'pd value (%)', pd;`
to print the value for debugging

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. :) You are life saver.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to do this as an edit, but the edit was rejected as being too small.

The problem you're running into is a misunderstanding of plpgsql's (somewhat confusing) [block syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql-structure.html). If you look on that page, the critical part you're missing is this:

```
[ DECLARE
    declarations ]
```

There can be **multiple declarations** in a single DECLARE section. You can also *nest* blocks:

```
DECLARE
  c_pi CONSTANT double precision := pi();
  v_text text;
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    v_blah text;
  BEGIN
    NULL;
  END;
END;
```

Note that the semicolon is optional on the outer-most block.